# importerror:no module name docker.client

Tags: docker, ansible

I've gotten a question when usde ansible to configurate a docker container.
  Here is my ansible playbook:

```
---
 -name: localhost
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - ansible_python_interpreter: python
  tasks:
   - name: busybox test
     docker: 
       image: busybox
       name: test
```

but when I run the file with :

```
 ansible-playbook ad.yml
```

I got following error:

```
from docker.client import APIError as DockerAPIError
ImportError: No module named docker.client
```

no docker.client? I have installed docker-py, but still got this question ,   how can I fix this ??    h....e....l....p....

Comment: Can you give us the output of:  pip freeze | grep docker-py && python --version && docker version && ansible --version

Comment: my os is SUSE , and I used zypper install ... to install these toos ,..       My python version :2.7.8                          docker version：1.9.1 API version:1.21                  ansible--version:1.7.1

Comment: a) Try adding "connection: local" to your playbook. b) check you have a single python installation; c) add a task to your playbook to install docker-py to the target host (altough it would seem not necessary because you are running on localhost (   - name: install docker-py
     pip: name=docker-py)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is caused by the way how I install the ansible. After I reinstall the ansible through python-pip, this problem has been solved successfully.

```
zypper install python-pip
pip install ansible
```

use this to solve the problem on suse.